# angular tutorial could not receive data from http call

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to learn Angular 2 by following the Tutorial Step 7 HTTP (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6). However the function `getHeroes()` in `hero.service.ts` still return nothing.

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

where the mock service is implemented from `InMemoryDbService`.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the HTTP client will fetch and save data from the in-memory web API `InMemoryDbService`. Basically, it means that `InMemoryDbService` will simulate your server that will receive HTTP request and will respond to them.

Did you install the module `in-memory-web-api`? If not, you can install it:  `npm install --save angular-in-memory-web-api`.

Don't forget to import the module in your app.module (this import should come only after the import of `HttpModule`):

```js
imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    ...
  ],
```

Also, a new change introduce in the new api of `in-memory-web-api` no longer wraps the HTTP response in the `data` property ([github](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api)). So it should be `response.json()` instead of `response.json().data`.

Comment: Did you add the module to your import dependencies in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: i did add InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),

Comment: Does the other functions of your `hero.service.ts` work or is `getHeroes` the only one that doesn't?

Comment: it is working if using `response.json()` instead of `response.json().data`